# How to add uploaded image from form to media library wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form. When submit button is pressed, the image gets uploaded but does not show in the media library.

How do you add image from form to media library?

**Html**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='file'>
<input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

**Wordpress**

```
if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' ); }

$uploaded_file = $_FILES['file'];

upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);

$file = wp_handle_upload($uploaded_file,$upload_overrides);

if ($file) {
echo "File is valid and was successfully uploaded";
var_dump($file);
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack";
}
```

I have done research and the code from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment does not work.

It needs the right wp_insert_attachment() to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [media_handle_upload()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_handle_upload) instead.

```
$return = media_handle_upload('file', 0);

if (is_int($return)) {
    echo "File is valid and was successfully uploaded. New ID: $return";
} else {
    var_dump($return);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note you are using $file variable and printing $movefile.So please

```
replace var_dump($movefile); with var_dump($file);
```

I think it will provide you some help

Comment: Your right. I'll fix that error. But that doesn't add the image to the media library.